# How can I fill up a second column of a dataframe with the values of a dictionary, where the first column values match dictionary keys?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe with a few columns, but for the sake of this question I'll only focus on one of those columns. This column is 20 rows long and has a bunch of categorical values. I have a dictionary with keys matching those categorical values, and I want to fill up a new column based on the values from the matching keys.
For example:

Dataframe:

| Project Name |
| --- |
| Project Alpha |
| Project Beta |
| Project Charlie |
| Project Alpha |
| Project Alpha |

Dictionary:

```
{ Project Alpha:Link to Alpha,
Project Beta:Link to Beta,
Project Charlie:Link to Charlie }
```

And I want to fill up a new column and append it to the dataframe so that the information is filled out if the column cell data and Key matches, like:

| Project Name | Link to Project |
| --- | --- |
| Project Alpha | Link to Alpha |
| Project Beta | Link to Beta |
| Project Charlie | Link to Charlie |
| Project Alpha | Link to Alpha |
| Project Alpha | Link to Alpha |

How can I do this easily? I know how to do it manually by matching keys and pulling the values, but I'm a little new to Python, so I'm not sure the most efficient way to do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

As an extra thing that's more difficult, if I have some of those cells containing multiple values that are comma separated, how would I pull out multiple values? For example, if a cell had "Alpha,Beta,Gamma", how would I output "Link to Alpha, Link to Beta, Link to Gamma" in the new column cell?

Comment: This is exactly what the `df.map` method is for.

Comment: @TimRoberts how would you make it work if there are multiple values in the first column of the dataframe? That won't work with df.map since there are multiple keys?

Comment: Correct.  There may be a cool answer, but it would be easy to do with `.apply`.

Comment: @BenKluger to map multiple comma separated keys, you can first split each value on comma and convert it to a list and then apply a function which maps and re-joins the values in the list. e.g.:  `fn = lambda x: ', '.join(mapping[item] for item in x)` and then do `df['Project Name'].str.split(', ').apply(fn)`